# How to get the position of the most significant bit

Tags: assembly, arm64

Using ARM64 assembly code, I'd like to know how I can get the index of the most significant bit.
For Example if `X0` has the value 9 (1001) I need to receive the value 3. If it has the value 24 (11000), I need to get the value 4.
I can do it with loops, but I assume that there is a instruction which does the same more quickly.

Comment: `clz` (count leading zeroes) instruction seems to be useful for this.

Comment: how does 1001 result in 4?  that is bit 3

Comment: @old_timer Sorry, you are 102% right, my bad. I'll fix it now.